# "Reading" the screen during ffmpeg recording

Tags: bash, image, ffmpeg

I am trying to write down a script which would record my screen using `ffmpeg` and stop automatically. I wonder if there is a way to somehow “read” the current screen and check it. I imagine it go something like this in bash:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -f x11grab -r 24 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -f pulse -an -ac 2 -i default -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v 500k $1&
# the `&` is added at the end of the first line to run ffmpeg in bg.
let “t=$2*95/100” #
sleep $t
until ???
 do
  sleep 60
done
killall -SIGINT ffmpeg
```

Note: It would probably look nicer in python with `skimage`. Also, using only seconds is not handy either. Yet those are details we may not worry about.

Comment: What do you mean *“read” the current screen and check it*?

Comment: @oguzismail sorry for poor wording. In python's `skimage` we have a function for getting access to images. It returns a matrix of triplets, encoding the color. I want to do the same for the user's screen. And checking is traversing through the matrix. Does my comment add clarity? Should I add it to the question?

Comment: Still not clear to me. If you're familiar with skimage I'd recommend using it for this. Giving examples from a python library doesn't help clarify a question that is tagged ffmpeg and bash

Comment: @oguzismail I've added an answer describing the algorithm. Basically, I want to get rid of `import -window ...` and put some `ffmpeg` feature in its place. Does my comment add clarity? Should I add it to the question itself? Sorry for this drawback once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have come up without the use of `ffmpeg` pictures is the following:

1. Take a screenshot: `import -window root /tmp/ffmpeg_rec_cur_screen.png`.
2. Open it with skimage's `imread('/tmp/ffmpeg_rec_cur_screen.png')`
3. Traverse the matrix.

Yet, I am still interested in solving this with `ffmpeg` only.